# select max salary in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

#### Emp table

```
id          ename
----------- ----------
1           apv
2           sug
3           raj
4           ram
5           sam
6           apv1
7           sug1
8           raj1
9           ram1
10          sam1
```

#### Dept Table

```
dept  salary      id
----- ----------- -----------
a     1000        1
b     2000        2
c     3000        3
d     5000        4
e     7000        5
a     20000       6
b     500         7
c     5000        8
a     1000        9
b     90000       10
```

How can I return both the `Max(salary)` from each dept and also the details of who earns that salary?
(select id,ename,dept,salary)

Comment: Can you rephrase this in the form of a question?

Comment: Have you tried to write a query to do this, or do you expect us to do your thinking for you?

Comment: select max(salary) from employees group by dept. maybe?

Comment: Your tables are horribly designed.  Why would an employee's salary be in the dept table?

Comment: No . i want display  each dept and all column

Comment: There is no table connection here - no way to determine what employee works in what department. There is no answer in this formulation.

Comment: @Victor - I assume the join is meant to be on `id`. @syrion - You've tagged this both `MySQL` and `SQL Server` does your answer need to work in both (lowest common denominator)?

Comment: My assumption is that Dept.id refers to Emp.id. @syrion, I'm guessing the naming is the problem and that it should maybe be person (with name and id) and emp tables (with id, dept and salary), but I see your point that it is a bit mangled.

Comment: Totally agree with the @syrion. These tables have a horrible construction. Putting the salary in with the department seems like a bad idea. The salery should be connected with the person, not the department as it seems salary is unique for each person and in no way controlled by what department they work for.

Comment: @Sondre but dept records are per-user - it seems to really be 'extra details for the user that happens to include department', it's not one record per department. Silly name though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @Emp table (id int, ename varchar(4))
declare @Dept table (dept char(1), salary int, id int)

insert into @Emp values
(1,           'apv'),
(2,           'sug'),
(3,           'raj'),
(4,           'ram'),
(5,           'sam'),
(6,           'apv1'),
(7,           'sug1'),
(8,           'raj1'),
(9,           'ram1'),
(10,          'sam1')

insert into @Dept values
('a',     1000,        1),
('b',     2000,        2),
('c',     3000,        3),
('d',     5000,        4),
('e',     7000,        5),
('a',     20000,       6),
('b',     500,         7),
('c',     5000,        8),
('a',     1000,        9),
('b',     90000,       10)

;with cte as
(
  select
    id,
    salary,
    dept,
    rank() over(partition by dept order by salary desc) as rn
  from @Dept
)
select
  e.ename,
  e.id,
  c.salary,
  c.dept
from cte as c
  inner join @Emp as e
    on c.id = e.id
where rn = 1
```

Result

```
ename id          salary      dept
----- ----------- ----------- ----
apv1  6           20000       a
sam1  10          90000       b
raj1  8           5000        c
ram   4           5000        d
sam   5           7000        e
```

Comment: Neat, but I don't think this copes with salary ties in a department?

Comment: @Rup It depends on what you want. With `rank` you will get all that share the highest salary. If you only want one of them you should use `row_number` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
select mm, d1.dept, d1.id, ename from DEPT D1,
(select max(salary) mm, dept from DEPT group by dept) D2, EMP 
where D2.mm=d1.salary and d2.dep=d1.dept
EMP.ID=DEPT.ID
```

Comment: Best so far, but I think you also need `and d2.dept = d1.dept`; else if the top employee in dept A earns 10000 then the query will also return all other employees that earn 10000 in other depts even if they're not the max for that dept. (And the last `DEPT.ID` should be `D1.ID`.)

Answer (score 1):

Prequery by department first, then go back to itself on same department and matching salary.  From THAT table, you can tie to the employee table.  This version will allow multiple people in the same department with the same salary to be pulled out... ex: 5 people in Dept X earning 75,000.

```
SELECT
      d1.Dept,
      d1.Salary,
      Emp.id,
      Emp.name
   from 
      ( SELECT
              dept,
              MAX(salary) MaxSal
           from 
              Dept
           group by 
              dept ) ByDept
      join Dept d1
         ON ByDept.dept = d1.dept
         and ByDept.MaxSal = d1.Salary
         join Emp
            ON d1.id = Emp.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand you at all but you can try something like:

```
   SELECT id, ename, dept, MAX(salary) AS salary
     FROM Dept_Table AS d
LEFT JOIN Emp_Table AS e
       ON e.id = d.id
 GROUP BY dept
```

Comment: Seems ok, but why a LEFT JOIN instead of a INNER JOIN ?

Comment: I don't think that'll work - you're selecting more non-aggregated columns than you're grouping by and I don't think it pulls in the max records as you expect. What if two employees have the same max salary for a given department?

Answer (score 0):

```
select dept.dept, max(dept.salary), emp.id, emp.ename
from emp inner join dept on emp.id=dept.id
group by dept.dept, emp.id, emp.ename
```

should do the trick, just know that if two people in same dept have same salary and it is the maximum salary you will have both people as outout.

Comment: No, that's grouping on too much - it's returning the max salary for each employee if it were possible for employees to have two dept table records.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT   emp.ename,dept.dept,max(dept.salary) from dept left join emp on dept.id=emp.id group by dept.dept